# Is it a good approach to encapsulate View and Model inside a dedicated Widget?

Tags: gui, qt, pyqt4

Lets say you have a `ItemView` and a `ItemModel`.

Would it make sense to have a `ItemWidget` encapsulating those two, so code using `ItemWidget` don’t have to deal with `ItemView` and a `ItemModel` specifics?

What would you miss doing so?

Comment: What code do you have that's dealing with both? Aren't you just collapsing the point of view and model separation here?

Answer (score 1):

If you use one of the many VM patterns, you *want* view and model to be separate. For example that lets you use the same model in multiple views. And the other way round there are plenty of situations where you keep using the same view and switch the model it displays.

So you wouldn’t put view and model into a single class.